# Pointcloud to surface in C#

Tags: c#, opencl, point-clouds

I am looking for a quick and relatively simple (which means i do not really want to code everything by myself...) solution to converse a pointcloud into a surface in C# (or OpenCL). Using some kind of program is out of the question.

I searched the web quite a bit already and cannot find a good solution in C# or OpenCL. The best approach i found so far is PCL which is C++. 
I also found papers about parallelisable algorithms for surface reconstruction but i would like to avoid implementing one of these algorithms without really understanding what it does (and even then there is hopefully an easier way).

Can anyone hint me in the right direction or, even better, give me some advice on what I could use?

So far i tried searching:
Surface reconstruction algorithms, Pointcloud to isosurface to marching cubes in OpenCL, parallel surface reconstruction algorithms, ...
Anything i missed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a ready-made library, I know of none other than the excellent, open-source [PCL](http://www.pcl-users.org/PCL-in-DotNet-td3666816.html) (point cloud library). Unfortunately, there are [no .NET bindings](http://www.pcl-users.org/PCL-in-DotNet-td3666816.html) to this library so you might have to write a wrapper by yourself in C++ CLI.

Depending on your needs and skills - implementing a paper might be easier than this. Or not.

Comment: honestly, I was hoping for another way (but did not really believe it either). Thanks anyway!